# How do I automatically refresh/run a function based on a timer?

Tags: javascript

How can I make a function, and have it run/refresh every (second) once in a while based on a timer? I'm trying to run a function and it needs to be updated to check if a parameter is checked.

```
function checkTime()  {
    if(document.getElementById("time").innerHTML === "12:00:00 PM")  {
        alert("It's noon!");
    }
}
```

Comment: You definitely should use jQuery for that.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished by using `setInterval()`. I am using something similar for this; I made a timer that shows the time that my period ends (in school) and also shows the current time, and when the time matches the period ends time, it should change to the next period automatically. With your example, you can do something like this:

```
//init function
function checkTime()  {
    //check if its noon
    if(document.getElementById("time").innerHTML === "12:00:00 PM")  {
        //alert
        alert("It's noon!");
    }
}
//set the interval
setInterval(function()  {
    //execute code 
    checkTime();
}, /* every 5 seconds, or 5000 milliseconds */ 5000);
```